# Throwing during unwinding -- why does this example work?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, terminate

Consider this:

```
void thrower () {
    throw "123";
}

struct Catcher {
    ~ Catcher () {
        try {thrower ();}
        catch (...) {}
    }
};

int main () {
    try {
       Catcher c;
       throw 1.23;
    }
    catch (...) {}
}
```

This compiles and runs without calling `terminate` on gcc 4.3, but [according to the standard](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/summer11/G22.2110-001/documents/c++2003std.pdf) (15.5.1)

> ...when the exception handling mechanism, after completing evaluation of the expression to be thrown but before the exception is caught (15.1), calls a user function that exits via an uncaught exception... terminate shall be called.

When `~Catcher` is called after the double has been thrown, this is "after completing evaluation...before the exception is caught" and `thrower` is "a user function that exits via an uncaught exception", *this satisfies the above condition*. Yes, the `char*` is caught but only *after* the user function exits.

Shouldn't `terminate` have been called?

To emphasise this:

```
void do_throw () {
    throw "123";
}

void thrower () {
    do_throw ();
    // Uncaught exception here (A)
}

struct Catcher {
    ~ Catcher () {
        try {thrower (); /* (B) */}
        catch (...) {}
    }
};

int main () {
    try {
       Catcher c;
       throw 1.23;
    }
    catch (...) {}
}
```

(A) happens in the context of (B), which already has an exception in progress.

So, shouldn't `terminate` have been called? If not, and this is a legal situation in which we can have two simultaneous exceptions, where do we draw the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different emphasis:

> when **the exception handling mechanism**, after completing evaluation of the expression to be thrown but before the exception is caught (15.1), **calls a user function** that exits via an uncaught exception... terminate shall be called

`thrower()` is a user function that exits via an exception but it is not called by the exception handling mechanism; it is called by another user function (`Catcher`'s destructor) which itself is called by the exception handling mechanism and this function *doesn't* exit via an exception.

Answer (score 4):

Why should `terminate` have been called? You have a `catch(...)` block which catches all exceptions: one that catches the `double` (the one in `main`) and one that catches the `char const[4]` (the one in `~Catcher`).

So no functions are "exiting with an uncaught exception" because all the exceptions are caught.

The key words here are "calls a user function which terminates with an uncaught exception". This is **not** the same as "calls a user function which somewhere down the line calls a user function which terminates with an uncaught exception." If you call a function and it has a `try/catch` block in it, and then in that you call some function which terminates with an exception *but* you catch the exception, `terminate` is not called.

tl;dr: The *very first call* in a call hierarchy originating between the exception evaluation and before the catch must exit with an exception for `terminate` to be called, *not* branches below the first call. This makes sense because there's no way you could set up *another* `catch` block between when the object being thrown was evaluated and  when it was caught.

Comment: The question he is asking is, while 1.23 is thrown and not yet caught, another function is called throwing 123 which is not caught by that function itself. So according to the standard, terminate should be called.

Answer (score 3):

Which function, called by the exception handling mechanism, exits via an
uncaught exception.  The only function called by the exception handling
mechanism here is `Catcher::~Catcher()`, and it exits normally, by
reaching the end of the function.

And there is fundamentally no limit to the number of simultaneously
active exceptions.  The limit is to the number of exceptions which must
be propagated up past a given point.  If `Catcher::~Catcher()` exited
via an exception, we would have two exceptions to propagate up, the one
which triggered the call of the destructor, and the one by which the
destructor exited.  As long as the destructor catches all exceptions,
and doesn't propagate them, there is no problem.

Answer (score 3):

> ...when the exception handling mechanism, after completing evaluation
>   of the expression to be thrown but before the exception is caught
>   (15.1), calls a user function that exits via an uncaught exception...
>   terminate shall be called.

The exception handling mechanism calls `~Catcher()`, which doesn't exit via an uncaught exception; hence it doesn't call `std::terminate`. It doesn't (directly) call `thrower()`.

Comment: `~Catcher` doesn't exit via an uncaught exception but `thrower` does

Comment: That sounds about right. "Calling a function" isn't defined recursively, it only refers to the present context.

Comment: @spraff: Yes, but the exception handling mechanism isn't calling `thrower()`. It's only calling `~Catcher()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly legal code.  You're catching everything that's thrown before it causes problems.
Only if you remove the try/catch in ~Catcher, you'd be throwing an exception during unwinding.